# jquery jqgrid date search not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I have implemented jqgrid jquery and applied search date but not filtering records.
Below is my code snippet.

```
// jquery jqgrid part
      { name: 'DateUpdated', index: 'DateUpdated',
                    sorttype: 'date'
                , sortable: true
                , datefmt: 'm/d/Y', width: 220, formatter: ndateFormatter,
                    formatoptions: { srcformat: 'm/d/Y', newformat: 'm/d/Y' },
                    searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'] }
                }
//    ------------------------------
    function ndateFormatter(cellval, opts, rwdat, _act) {

                                    var time = cellval.replace(/\/Date\(([0-9]*)\)\//, '$1');
                                    var date = new Date();
                                    date.setTime(time);
                                    return (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();

                                }
```

I also applied datepicker in search options but it is not filtering with date.

Comment: Could you explain the sense of the custom formatter `ndateFormatter`. Which is input format for the column 'DateUpdated'? Do you use local data or load jqGrid from remote data source?

Comment: Yes, Actually in json date comes like "DateUpdated": "\/Date(1335807000433)\/" which I convert it to normal date format.

Comment: The standard Date formatter supports the input format. See [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L130-L131) and [some lines later](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L153-L160).

Comment: See additionally [my old feature request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/sopport-for-microsoft-date-format-date1285128000000/) with the corresponding implementation which I wrote too.

Comment: I tried but seems not working. I just replaced formatter file.

Comment: I have jqgrid.min file which already includes formater and other files in it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow you. Which versions of jqGrid, jQuery and jQuery UI you use? If you want debug the code you can use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`

Comment: I used jqgrid.src file after too. and using jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js.

Comment: **Which versions of jqGrid and jQuery you use?**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26486/discussion-between-keyur-and-oleg)

Comment: <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Which versions of **jqGrid** you use??? If you ignore my questions I'll not spend my time more.

Comment: jqGrid  3.8 - jQuery Grid => BTW, I am not ignoring your question offcourse. I was in chat for 20 minutes!

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: jqGrid 3.8 is already retro version. In [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/sopport-for-microsoft-date-format-date1285128000000/) which I referenced before I describe the implementation of support MS Date format in jqGrid. In [the file](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/src/jquery.fmatter-fixed.js) you will find `DateFormat` method. Just compare it with the version of jqGrid which you have and you can make the same modifications yourself.

Comment: Ok, will give it try and update. Many thanks for your prompt help and inputs. Very much appreciated.